# SQL group by - which records are grouped

Tags: sql, firebird

Following data I have:

Table1

```
ID   Name  Qty  Len  Wid
1    Name1 1    100  200
2    Name1 3    100  200
3    Name2 2    200  300
4    Name2 1    200  300
5    Name2 2    200  300
```

Result I need:

```
Name  SumQty  Len  Wid JoinedId
Name1 4       100  200 1,2
Name2 5       200  300 3,4,5
```

With this sql I get sumQty

```
select  Name,  Len,  Wid,   SUM(Qyt) as SumQty
from Table1
group by 1,2,3
```

How to establish, which records are grouped together and get their IDs comma separated in one string?

I'm using firebird sql server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For firebird 2.1 you can use [LIST](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-aggrfunc-list.html)

> LIST ([ALL | DISTINCT] expression [, separator])

```
select  Name,  Len,  Wid,   SUM(Qyt) as SumQty, LIST(ID)
from Table1
group by 1,2,3
```